# How to fix "fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/time.h': No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, python-3.x

I have been trying to install the Python package ElPeriodic (through pip install ElPeriodic) on windows using Python 3.8.10.

It first gave an error asking for the installation of the C++ Build Tools for Visual Studio, so I installed Visual Studio Community 2022. During the installation I checked the following workloads:  Python development (plus optional 'Python native development tools'), Desktop development with C++, Universal Windows Platform development, Visual Studio extension development.

After the installation of VS 2022, and a reboot, I tried to pip install ElPeriodic once more but it keeps giving me the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" 

/c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD  

-IC:\Users\gaan\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\k3_analysis\include 

-IC:\Users\gaan\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\k3_analysis\Include 

"-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\include" 

"-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\ATLMFC\include" 

"-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" 

"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" 

"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" 

"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" 

"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" 

"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\incl ude\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" 

"-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" 

/Tcsrc/periodic.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\src/periodic.obj       

periodic.c       

src/periodic.c(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/time.h': No such file or directory

error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

The problem is the missing header file 'sys/time.h', but since this is a POSIX header I guess it is not installed with Visual Studio. I have also installed MinGW which should have POSIX libraries and headers, if I am not mistaken. But I don't know if it can be useful or how.

There is no 'time.h' file in "\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\sys".

I would appreciate any and all suggestions on how to fix this issue, thank you for your help!

Comment: looks like that library simply isn't written for running on windows, if you raise an issue on their github page, the author might fix it for you